# JS error with Braintree - no clientToken?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to implement Braintree payments into a Magento 2.1.2 store.

I have followed these guides to set it up, and added in my merchant ID, public and private key:
http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/braintree.html

In checkout, when I click on the Braintree payment method radio button, I get the following JS error:

```
braintree-2.17.6.min.js:3 Uncaught Error: Braintree API Client Misconfigured: clientToken required.
```

Shouldn't the client Token be created OK if I've put in all the keys?

This is running in a local dev environment, is that the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

For future Googlers, the problem was I was using incorrect API keys. Remember that if you have Braintree configured to be in Sandbox mode in Magento admin, then you will need to be using Sandbox API keys too.

Comment: This worked for us thank you - annoying that the error isn't better worded!

Answer (score 2):

For other future Googlers, this was caused because I had not checked "Api access" for the user that generates the Braintree API Keys (done by editing their Account). I also got the error

> Attention This payment is not available

in the admin area when trying to create a new sale as a result of this.

I would recommend that you set up a user just for the API access, don't have this any one persons account and limit to only have permission to do this.

Comment: Can you please add more details here